# How to deal with conflicting health advice?

Tags: nutrition, diet, research

With all the information on health how can I know who is accurate?

Healthline ( [7](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/saturated-fat-good-or-bad#section5) ) claims that saturated fat is not bad for you while Harvard ( [6](https://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/the-truth-about-fats-bad-and-good) ) claims it is a bad fat.

Comment: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1231/are-saturated-fats-unhealthy may help

Comment: A big issue here is that Western style diets in general, even the healthier versions such as the Mediterranean diet, are quite far removed from what is optimal. There exist diets that lead to almost zero rate of coronary heart disease, [see here](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/41/5/1225/712708), and [here](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(17)30752-3/fulltext). By keeping total fat intake below 20% of total calorie intake and get plenty of exercise, eat whole grains plenty of vegetables, your risk of coronary heart disease plummets to near zero.

Comment: Now, the human body is a very complex system that isn't going to fail when straying away from the optimum. There are a large number of biochemical processes that are constantly at work to repair your arteries. When you stray away from the optimum, these processes will be modified so that to a first approximation you don't get problems. Almost all the damage will still be repaired, but not exactly as good as when sticking to the optimum lifestyle. Then suppose we constrain the body to operate very far from the optimum, and only look at changing one variable a bit.

Comment: Suppose we're going to consider changing the saturated fat content of the diet, when the overall diet and lifestyle are very far removed from the optimum. Then there is no guarantee that the result will be that you get a better outcome by changing that single variable in the direction of what that single variable is in the optimum. There may well be local optima nearby the true global optimum that are much closer to the average diet and lifestyle that would make a small toward the opposite direction from the global optimum yield a better result.

Comment: go with established sites http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/HealthyLiving/HealthyEating/Nutrition/Frequently-Asked-Questions-About-Saturated-Fats_UCM_463756_Article.jsp?appName=MobileApp

Comment: Harvard vs. some company running a web site that serves up ads.... hmmm.

Answer (score 4):

The best method to verify the autenticity of a scientific news, is to search authorized papers about the subject.

You can find all the published papers on this website: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/

Here, and especially on "PubMed" and "PubMed Central (PMC)" (both within ncbi.gov) you can search for a topic and a lot of papers will be shown. Then look for the most recent one, since sometimes newer reviews discover something important.

In your case, this can be a good starting point.

Comment: I find [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.uk) a good source, as sometimes I have found that not only do they direct you do the PubMed and PubMed Central pages, but they also sometimes take you straight to the source rather than through the NCBI.  Searches sometimes also link you to free copies of PDFs (on the right hand side of the search list) which are not always available through NCBI.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Yes, google scholar is another useful tool. The advantage is that when an author send a paper to a journal, usually he put his email in the contact box, which can be linked to his Google profile. This allows you to keep track of the papers you send to journals (and you also get a notification when your work is cited by other authors, if I'm not wrong). 
So it is quite the same, but in google Scholar you have also the power of Google search engine.